# SSIS Execute Process Task for Python script to API with OAuth2 - Access denied to the file with saved token

Tags: python, windows, ssis, oauth-2.0, business-intelligence

I have strange problem and don't know what to check further.

Summary of the situation:

- working on the Windows Server 2016 as administrator, so should not have any access problems
- developed some Python script for getting data from Google Analytics using , as basis took [this example](http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/) (but getting data only from one account and only for one time interval)
- script successfully works: withing the first time code of API execution opens GA Web Site in browser, requests for authorization and approves API connection, creates `analytics.dat` file with store connection token inside
- right after that all the next script executions successfully get information from GA and save it in file
- but when I trying to add the same script execution into SSIS Package as `Execute Process Task` step and executing that step (Visual Studio is opened under the same administrator account withing the same active windows session) - it requests again authorization on the web-site, after successful authorization I see `The authentication flow has completed` message in browser, close it, but getting the error of Python script's execution:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py:255:
>   UserWarning: Cannot access analytics.dat: No such file or directory
>   warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
>
> Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> ```
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline
> ```
>
> If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
>   application with the command-line parameter
>
> `--noauth_local_webserver`
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py",
>   line 172, in 
>       if **name** == '**main**': main(sys.argv)   File "C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py",
>   line 54, in main
>       scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\sample_tools.py", line
>   93, in init
>       credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py", line 133, in
>   positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\tools.py", line 247, in
>   run_flow
>       storage.put(credential)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 421, in
>   put
>       self.locked_put(credentials)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\file.py", line 83, in
>   locked_put
>       self._create_file_if_needed()
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\file.py", line 70, in
>   _create_file_if_needed
>       open(self._filename, 'a+b').close() IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'analytics.dat'

- I tried to delete that file `analytics.dat` - but after that getting the same error.
- I executed Python script by `.bat` file with the command inside `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py`. Execution of the `.bat` itselft works fine, but execution of the same `.bat` from SSIS Package as `Execute Process Task` step - returns the errors above
- Also, had the same problem before with [Bing Ads API](https://github.com/arkhipkin/Python_API_BingAds/blob/master/Destination%20URL%20Custom%20Report%20-%20Report%20Request%20and%20Download/DestinationUrlPerformanceReportRequestAndDownload.ipynb). But there I temporary fixed that by commented out line in the code with re-writing of updated token information to the file: in Bing Ads it is valid long time before expiring. But in the GA API that token in file expires after 1 hour and after that that file need to be overwritten.
- also, I tried to add into scripts some prints to show under which service account script executes from SSIS package in Visual Studio (using `print(os.getlogin())`) - but as expected it shows the same administrator account under which I am working on the Server...

So, I don't understand, why I am getting such Access denied to the file with saved token problem...
In the properties of the file the owner - is the same Windows Administrator account, under whose session I am opening Visual Studio for execution of the step in DTSX package.

Could you help me to find the problem, please?

Comment: May have to do with where you are placing the .dat file. I am not an expert  with Python or api's, but in general, this looks like the analytics.dat file is being created at the wrong spot.

Comment: What is the fully qualified path to the `analytics.dat` file?

Comment: @rvphx @lit the full path to `analytics.dat` file: `C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\analytics.dat`

Comment: I executed Python script by `.bat` file with the command inside `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py`. Execution of the `.bat` itselft works fine, but execution of the same `.bat` from SSIS Package as `Execute Process Task` step - returns the errors above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787699/google-analytics-dat-file-missing-falling-back-to-noauth-local-webserver?rq=1 - seems there was a similar problem, but did not get solution either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. And it was related with the properties of `Execute Process Task` step of SSIS Package...

As I noticed above, I executed Python script by `.bat` file with the command inside:
`C:\Python27\python.exe C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py`.
Execution of the `.bat` itself worked fine, but execution of the same `.bat` from SSIS Package as `Execute Process Task` step - returns the errors above.

In the logs of errors in the beginning we see:

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn**> `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\google_analytics_api_v3_10krows_nosampling_multiple_profiles.py`
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py:260: UserWarning: Cannot access analytics.dat: No such file or directory
>
> warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))

What says initially, that there is no file `analytics.dat` in the working folder of script.
But I expected, that script executes in the same folder where it is located and there already had existed file `C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\analytics.dat`

But then I noticed, that on the first place in that message (I marked it as **bold**) is working folder of the external script execution, script starts in the SSIS folder.

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700333/ssis-execute-process-task-does-not-write-files), that when the process is launched from SSIS, it's not being run from the same folder as the executable `.bat` file located.
What is different from the direct `.bat` file execution.

**So, it is necessary additionally specify working folder property of `Execute Process Task` step of SSIS Package.**

I set such property value:

**Working directory:** `C:\BI\API\Python_GoogleAnalytics_Reporting\v3_api_analytics\`
[image]

And everything works fine!